# Entity Framework auto-determination whether to update or create entity

Tags: entity-framework, orm, crud

I'm new to EF. 
After searching hours on the internet I want to ask my question in here.

Is there really no built-in mechanism in EF to determine, whether to update or create an entity?

Suppose I have a list of POCO objects and want to save them into the database.

Now I really have to distinguish, whether an entity exists already (update) or not (insert) with context.Add and have to do lookups before the processing?

I expected, when the primary key field is null or empty, then the EF will automatically perform an insert, otherwise an update?

Comment: Short answer - no. It's your responsibility to tell EF what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IvanStoev mentioned with his comment the short answer is

> no. It's your responsibility to tell EF what to do.

But there is a hack you can use. `AddOdUpdate` extension method in `System.Data.Entity.Migrations` namespace.

Anyway, I do believe it is not a good idea to use it in your case. You should control what you are doing in your code and every time you are trying to hack something, it means you are not doing it correctly. I recommend you to read attached links.

Related links:

[AddOrUpdate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbsetmigrationsextensions.addorupdate(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate%60%601(System.Data.Entity.IDbSet%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,System.Object%7D%7D,%60%600[]))

[Entity Framework: AddOrUpdate is a Destructive Operation](http://www.michaelgmccarthy.com/2016/08/24/entity-framework-addorupdate-is-a-destructive-operation/)

Comment: Another point against `AddOrUpdate` is that it doesn't work well with navigation properties. I never use it and don't recommend using it for anything else than simple entity seeding. The only attempt to address the issue with applying disconnected entity modifications is the third party package [GraphDiff](https://github.com/zzzprojects/GraphDiff).